# order csv report

Tags: magento2

I created module and there is cron job in module which will run every Monday and it will take all the data of the product from ordered.
What i do if same product order more than 1 customer so i make 1 row and add qty and price but if the price of product change then i create separate row of that product if its ordered after price change and below is my code which work perfectly if price change 1 time but more than 2 its break

```
 $orders = $this->getOrderCollectionByDateRange();
            $ordersMerged = [];
            $ordersMergedProductsDifferentPrice = [];

            foreach ($orders as $order) {
                foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                    $totalPrice = $item->getQtyOrdered() * $item->getPrice();

                    if (!array_key_exists($item->getSku(), $ordersMerged)) {
                        // Add new item to $ordersMerged
                        $item->setOrderCreatedAt($order->getCreatedAt());
                        $item->setTotalPrice($totalPrice);
                        $ordersMerged[$item->getSku()] = $item;
                    } else {
                        // Check if the same product has different price
                        if ($ordersMerged[$item->getSku()]->getPrice() != $item->getPrice()) {
                            // Update qty and price for existing item in $ordersMergedProductsDifferentPrice
                            if (array_key_exists($item->getSku(), $ordersMergedProductsDifferentPrice) &&
                                $ordersMergedProductsDifferentPrice[$item->getSku()]->getPrice() == $item->getPrice()
                            ) {
                                $totalQty =
                                    $ordersMergedProductsDifferentPrice[$item->getSku()]->getQtyOrdered() + $item->getQtyOrdered();
                                $totalPrice = $totalQty * $item->getPrice();
                                $ordersMergedProductsDifferentPrice[$item->getSku()]->setQtyOrdered($totalQty);
                                $ordersMergedProductsDifferentPrice[$item->getSku()]->setTotalPrice($totalPrice);
                            } else {
                                // Add new item to $ordersMergedProductsDifferentPrice
                                $item->setOrderCreatedAt($order->getCreatedAt());
                                $item->setTotalPrice($totalPrice);
                                $ordersMergedProductsDifferentPrice[$item->getSku()] = $item;
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Update qty and price for existing item in $ordersMerged
                            $totalQty = $ordersMerged[$item->getSku()]->getQtyOrdered() + $item->getQtyOrdered();
                            $totalPrice = $totalQty * $item->getPrice();
                            $ordersMerged[$item->getSku()]->setQtyOrdered($totalQty);
                            $ordersMerged[$item->getSku()]->setTotalPrice($totalPrice);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach ($ordersMerged as $item) {

                $data['sku'] = $item->getSku();
                $data['name'] = $item->getName();
                $data['price'] = $item->getTotalPrice();
                $data['qty'] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
                $data['created_at'] = $item->getOrderCreatedAt();
                $stream->writeCsv($data);
            }

            foreach ($ordersMergedProductsDifferentPrice as $item) {

                $data['sku'] = $item->getSku();
                $data['name'] = $item->getName();
                $data['price'] = $item->getTotalPrice();
                $data['qty'] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
                $data['created_at'] = $item->getOrderCreatedAt();
                $stream->writeCsv($data);
            }
```

some on suggest me this logic but i dont know how to implement ? logic below

One way simplier way is to create an prices array for each SKU containing the quantity / totalPrice.
Than foreach on each items->prices() to create the csv. No more limit, way more readable code.